# systemd service to mount google drive directories with gdfuse not working

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, google-drive

I have a simple service that launches a script that mounts google drive directories via [gdfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse). The script works when run manually from the terminal. It fails when launched using systemd, which seems to be the only up-to-date method of setting a script to run on startup from my hours of searching.

Here is the systemd service `gdrive.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount google drives

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/james/gdrive.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                             
/usr/bin/google-drive-ocamlfuse -label mydrive /home/james/GoogleDrive/MyDrive/
/usr/bin/google-drive-ocamlfuse -label shareddrive /home/james/GoogleDrive/SharedDrive/
/usr/bin/google-drive-ocamlfuse -label shareddrive2 /home/james/GoogleDrive/SharedDrive2/
```

And here is the systemctl status when I try to start the service (and yes I have run systemctl daemon-reload):

```
× gdrive.service - Mount google drives
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gdrive.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-09-14 15:41:19 PDT; 1s ago
    Process: 4997 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/james/gdrive.sh (code=exited, status=2)
   Main PID: 4997 (code=exited, status=2)
        CPU: 24ms

Sep 14 15:41:19 blister systemd[1]: Started Mount google drives.
Sep 14 15:41:19 blister bash[4998]: Fatal error: exception Not_found
Sep 14 15:41:19 blister bash[4999]: Fatal error: exception Not_found
Sep 14 15:41:19 blister bash[5000]: Fatal error: exception Not_found
Sep 14 15:41:19 blister systemd[1]: gdrive.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Sep 14 15:41:19 blister systemd[1]: gdrive.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have also replaced gdrive.sh with a simple `echo hello` script and it launches successfully, so my systemd setup is functioning in principle... based on the errors, it seems like when run from systemd, the google-drive-ocamlfuse command is not being found (even though I replaced everything with absolute paths just in case). If it helps, I am on Xubuntu.

Comment: Try running: `sudo journalctl -xe --unit=gdrive.service` and check the log. It can give more useful information.

Comment: That error is not coming from bash, it's coming from the fuse command. Looks like something is needed from your `PATH` or elsewhere in the environment - maybe dump `env` output to a file and check for what's missing